# ODE from Gazebo and ROS

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have several questions about Gazebo, ODE and their integration in ROS:

1- As Gazebo wraps ODE in its world files, where can I find documentation about all the parameters of ODE that can be accessed from Gazebo? I couldn't find any complete documentation neither in the ROS wiki nor in Gazebo web page. I am just using example world files and ODE manuals to figure out the parameters.

2- I am working with very heavy mobile platforms in simulation (around 40000 kg). One of the most important things is to know whether the wheels are sliping. Does anybody know how to calculate the slip angle in Gazebo? Is there any ODE related function that could help?

3- Finally, the roadmap for the 1.0 version of Gazebo seems very promising, but is there any estimated release data? What's about the use of Bullet in Gazebo? I mean, can Gazebo just switch the physics motor to use Bullet instead of ODE?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9702/ode-from-gazebo-and-ros/) by [gazkune](https://answers.ros.org/users/165/gazkune/) on ROS Answers with karma: 219 on 2011-04-11

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-04-21**:
You should probably split this into 3 separate questions on ROS-ANSWERS so that they can be answered individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation in the current version of gazebo is a bit lacking. Example world files is your besst friend.

2. are you trying to calculate the angle at which the wheels slip? If that's the case, then you'll have to write your own controller to look at wheel velocity and model velocity. There is no function to my knowledge in ode that exposes this information.
3. the new gazebo website has more info: gazebo.willowgarage.com

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.ros.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 431 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-06-29**:
just a comment for 2), take a look at the fdir1 parameter.  Without setting fdir1, the friction pyramid will make your slippage non-isotropic in the global coordinate system.  Currently, specifying fdir1 fixes the friction directions to body frame, one can try aligning it with slip direction too.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. The upcoming version of Gazebo will expose many of these parameters.
2. I'm not sure, please ask this seperately.
3. It's targeted for release into Electric in August.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3